# android listview deletion animation is automatically deleting a second item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-arrayadapter

I have a list view with a custom adapter. Each item has a delete icon which prompts a delete dialog fragment. on deleting the item, I am performing a slide animation and on animation end. the item is deleted from the list and adapter is notified about the deletion like below:

```
// dialog fragment on clicking "delete"
positive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final FoldingCell fView = (FoldingCell) thisItem.getParent().getParent();

// wait for fold to finish then delete item
                fView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        deleteCell(fView, pos);

                    }
                }, 850);
```

my adapter is of type `FoldingCell` so I am folding back the cell before deletion, hence the `postDelayed`. The `deleteCell` is the simple animation below:

private void deleteCell(final View v, final int index) {

```
    TranslateAnimation transanim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 800, 0, 0);
    transanim.setDuration(700);

    transanim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            items.remove(index);

            // update array adapter
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    v.startAnimation(transanim);
}
```

An important not is that I also am using `stableIds` which might be causing the problem. After the animation deletion occurs, the adapter is deleting two items instead of just the one clicked on. when I disable the animation in the above code, and just write

```
    items.remove(index);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

exactly on delete, the deletion works perfectly even with `stable ids` (there is just no animation) why is that? The problem seems like its a combination of the animation and `stable ids`, since if `stableids` is false, the deletion works with the animation.

I cannot find a good solution for this other than making `stable ids` false and solve other issues that arise from doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The reason why with stableids the adapter was deleting an extra fields was that when I override `getItemId`, I was returning the adapter position itself which, I guess, during the animation when an item is deleted, that same position id is taken by another list item which gets deleted as well. By returning a different itemId that is unique to the list item, this error does not occur. so I changed this:

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

to this:

```
@Override

public long getItemId(int position) {
    Item item = items(position);
    return item.getId();
}
```

where `items` is the `arraylist` I am passing to the `adapter`. Item is my class that holds the elements/views of each item and `getId()` is the getter I have to return the `id` integer of each `Item`